# Description of the algebra of $G$-invariant polynomials by generators and relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, representation-theory, invariant-theory

Fix $n > 1$ and let $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity. Let $G \subset \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ be a cyclic subgroup of order $n$ generated by the diagonal matrix $g = \text{diag}(\zeta, \zeta^{-1})$. The group $G$ acts naturally on $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$. Let $\mathbb{C}[x, y]^G$ be the algebra of $G$-invariant polynomials, namely $$\mathbb{C}[x, y]^G = \{f \in \mathbb{C}[x, y] : f(\zeta^{-1}x, \zeta y) = f(x, y)\}.$$What is the description of the algebra $\mathbb{C}[x, y]^G$ in terms of  generators and relations?

Comment: If I were to guess I'd say $x^n,y^n,xy$ together generate the algebra. But I have not tried to prove it.

Comment: I'm sure you can prove that the answer is what @MattSamuel suggested. Hint: Any monomial spans a 1-dimensional $G$-submodule, and we get all of $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ as the direct sum of such. The remaining task is to check which monomials are acted upon trivially by $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the group $G$ has the order $n$ then by Noether's  upper bound  theorem for generator of the algebra  invariants is a polynomial  of degree $ \leq n.$ 
Let us consider the Reynolds average operator $R: \mathbb{C}[x,y] \to \mathbb{C}[x,y]^G$:
$$
R=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{g \in G} g.
$$

Then, by direct calculation we get
$R((xy)^k)=(xy)^k, k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $R(x^k)=\delta_{k,n} x^k$ and $R(y^k)=\delta_{k,n} y^k.$

So, $\mathbb{C}[x,y]^G=\mathbb{C}[x^n,y^n,xy].$  The relation $x^n \cdot y^n=(xy)^n.$